# .htaccess directory wildcard redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Please can someone tell me why this isn't working?

I am trying to redirect all files within the directory "Kent". In this example the page to be redirected is "ramsgate" and change the folder structure.

from:

```
/electrical-contractors/kent/ramsgate.php
```

to:

`/electrical-contractors-ramsgate/`

Using a wildcard redirect, why doesn't this work?

```
RedirectMatch 301 /electrical-contractors/kent/(.*).php /electrical-contractors-$1/
```

Comment: Is `/electrical-contractors/` also a directory? Does `http://domain.com/electrical-contractors-ramsgate/` a working URL?

Comment: /electrical-contractors/ yes that is a directory.

Comment: http://domain.com/electrical-contractors-ramsgat‌​e/ yes that is a working url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have this rule inside **`/electrical-contractors/kent/.htaccess`**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /electrical-contractors-$1/ [L,NC,R=301]
```